# Need to Load multiple App in UWSGI

Tags: python, uwsgi, falconframework

I am writing Rest in Python Falcon.I have some scenario like:

Lets say I have file A.py which have some /a api and I have one more file B.py which have api /b.
        And i want to load both A.py and B.py using some c.py in uwsgi...so once i launch c.py in uwsgi ...both API should be accessible.

Thanks
    Sumit

Comment: I have done it using http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just have to register the views/resources under the desired url

```
import falcon
from my_resource import MyResource
from my_other_resource import MyOtherResource

app = falcon.API()
app.add_route('/a', MyResource())
app.add_route('/b', MyOtherResource())
```

theres a lightweight framework that works with both fakcon and flask, that lets you do that, and many other cool things and makes building apis super easy (I've made it)

https://github.com/sebastiandev/peach